# How to set index on sidemenu Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a project that fetches data from WordPress 
I using for loop to get category from WordPress and put into side menu 
but I don't know how to get index of that array and customize it one by one

**Ionic side menu code**

```
<ion-list>
  <button color="primary" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
     <ion-icon name="add" item-left></ion-icon>
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

**Loop i using**

```
api.category().subscribe(datas =>{
      //title: datas[1].name
      //id: datas[0].id
      for (let i of datas){
        this.pages.push({
        title : i.name,      
        id:i.id
        })
```

Comment: You can do `*ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index"`

Comment: can you give me full code exam

Comment: i newbie and i dont know well about it

Comment: What do you want to do with the index? Where do you want the index?